# 親子関係にある多層boxcolliderによる処理においてのエラー

Tags: c#, unity3d

段差を登るシステムを作っていたのですが、
スクリプトからgetcomponentしようとすると、

> c:\Users\user\Documents\New Unity Project 3\Assets\Standard Assets\Characters\ThirdPersonCharacter\Scripts\ThirdPersonCharacter.cs(4,4): Error CS0246: 型または名前空間名 'dansacollider1' が見つかりませんでした。using ディレクティブまたはアセンブリ参照が不足しています。 (CS0246) (Assembly-CSharp-firstpass)

とでてビルドエラーになります。

[参考サイト](http://myoujing.wpblog.jp/2014/06/760/)

・構造

・Thirdpersoncontroller
　・モデル
　・dansacolloder1
　　・dansacolloder2
　　　・dansacolloder3
　　　　・dansacolloder4
　　　　　・dansacolloder5

・スクリプト

・thirdpersoncontroller.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
    [RequireComponent(typeof(CapsuleCollider))]
    [RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]
    public class ThirdPersonCharacter : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] float m_MovingTurnSpeed = 360;
        [SerializeField] float m_StationaryTurnSpeed = 180;
        [SerializeField] float m_JumpPower = 12f;
        [Range(1f, 4f)][SerializeField] float m_GravityMultiplier = 2f;
        [SerializeField] float m_RunCycleLegOffset = 0.2f; //specific to the      character in sample assets, will need to be modified to work with others
    [SerializeField] float m_MoveSpeedMultiplier = 1f;
    [SerializeField] float m_AnimSpeedMultiplier = 1f;
    [SerializeField] float m_GroundCheckDistance = 0.1f;

    Rigidbody m_Rigidbody;
    Animator m_Animator;
    bool m_IsGrounded;
    float m_OrigGroundCheckDistance;
    const float k_Half = 0.5f;
    float m_TurnAmount;
    float m_ForwardAmount;
    Vector3 m_GroundNormal;
    float m_CapsuleHeight;
    Vector3 m_CapsuleCenter;
    CapsuleCollider m_Capsule;
    bool m_Crouching;


    //段差システム

    bool dansatrigger = false;
    bool dc1 = false;
    bool dc2 = false;
    bool dc3 = false;
    bool dc4 = false;
    bool dc5 = false;


    void Start()
    {
        m_Animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        m_Rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        m_Capsule = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>();
        m_CapsuleHeight = m_Capsule.height;
        m_CapsuleCenter = m_Capsule.center;

        m_Rigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationX | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationY | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationZ;
        m_OrigGroundCheckDistance = m_GroundCheckDistance;

        //段差システム





    }

    public void update()
    {

        //段差システム

        var f_dc1 = GameObject.Find("dansacollider1");

        dansacollider1 g_dc1 = f_dc1.GetComponent<dansacollider1>();

        g_dc1.dansatrigger1 = dc1;

        var f_dc2 = GameObject.Find("dansacollider2");

        dansacollider1 g_dc2 = f_dc2.GetComponent<dansacollider2>();

        g_dc2.dansatrigger2 = dc2;

        var f_dc3 = GameObject.Find("dansacollider3");

        dansacollider3 g_dc3 = f_dc3.GetComponent<dansacollider3>();

        g_dc3.dansatrigger3 = dc3;

        var f_dc4 = GameObject.Find("dansacollider4");

        dansacollider4 g_dc4 = f_dc4.GetComponent<dansacollider4>();

        g_dc4.dansatrigger4 = dc4;

        var f_dc5 = GameObject.Find("dansacollider5");

        dansacollider5 g_dc5 = f_dc5.GetComponent<dansacollider5>();

        g_dc5.dansatrigger5 = dc5;




        if (dc1){

                            //段差１処理
            m_Animator.SetFloat("dansaheight",1);
            dansatrigger = true;


            if(dc2){
                //段差２処理
                m_Animator.SetFloat("dansaheight",2);
                dansatrigger = true;

                if(dc3){
                    //段差３処理
                    m_Animator.SetFloat("dansaheight",3);
                    dansatrigger = true;


                    if(dc4){
                        //段差４処理
                        m_Animator.SetFloat("dansaheight",4);
                        dansatrigger = true;


                        if(dc5){
                            //段差５処理
                            m_Animator.SetFloat("dansaheight",5);
                            dansatrigger = true;
                        }

                    }

                }


            }



                    }
        else{

            dansatrigger = false;

                    }

            }
```

・dansacollider1~5

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class dansacollider1 : MonoBehaviour {

public bool dansatrigger1;



// Use this for initialization
public void Start () {

    dansatrigger1 = false;

}

// 衝突した瞬間に呼ばれる
public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "dansa"){
        dansatrigger1 = true;
    }
}

// 衝突から離れた瞬間に呼ばれる
public void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) {
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "dansa") {
        dansatrigger1 = false;
    }
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unityのプロジェクト内スクリプトは、特定のフォルダによってコンパイル順が異なります。
　コンパイル順は以下のリンクのUnityドキュメントに記載してあります。
　http://docs.unity3d.com/ja/current/Manual/ScriptCompileOrderFolders.html
　
　質問内容を見るとThirdPersonCharacter.csはStandard Assetsフォルダに含まれていることがわかります。
　Standard Assetsフォルダは早い段階でコンパイルされるため、Standard Assetsフォルダ外のスクリプトは参照できません。
　質問内容からはdansacollider1.csがどのフォルダの中に入っているのは分かりませんが、Standard Assetsフォルダ外のフォルダに入っているのではないでしょうか。
　ご確認ください。